# language parameter in geocoder.geocode()?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I am trying to fetch the address components using Google Maps APIs.

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
marker = new google.maps.Marker(...);
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(...);
```

But for some cases when I drag the marker to point to exact location, I get few parts of address_components in response of GeoCoding API in localised versions even though the map language is set to "en" (English).

Is there any way I can pass in language param while creating Geocoder instance to force it to return address components in english only.

NOTE: I am not using geocoding webservice to get the address_components.

Comment: Besides Language Localization, try applying [Region Localization](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Region) as well. You may change the value of region field in [Geocoding Requests](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRequests).

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't each component available in each desired language

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328701/change-the-language-in-which-geocoder-geocode-returns-results